# How do Inverse Battles affect moves that would usually do zero damage?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

There's a house on Route 18 in Pokémon X & Y, where you can take part in an Inverse Battle once per day. In this battle moves that are usually Super Effective (eg, Fire -> Grass) are Not Very Effective, and moves that are usually Not Very Effective (eg, Water -> Grass) are Super Effective.

How does this affect match-ups that usually do **no** damage (eg Normal -> Ghost, or Psychic -> Dark)? Do they still do zero damage, or do they now do Super Effective? If the latter, are there any type match-ups that would do zero damage in an Inverse Battle?

Comment: Maybe immunity becomes an insta-kill? That, or it leads to 8x damage. I was actually wondering the same thing myself.

Comment: I'm attempting to investigate this now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Edit:Turns out I can't read charts.*

Your second instinct was correct -- these attacks now do super-effective (2x) damage. There are no immunities added in the inverse battle, so "not-very-effective" (.5x or .25x) is now the worst things can get.

Serebii has compiled the entirety of the inverse type-chart, which you can [view here](http://serebii.net/xy/inverse.shtml).